# How to detect and deliver separate CSS files for mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I'm trying to detect a mobile device and load a separate CSS file if it is a mobile device. Why doesn't my code work?

```
    var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};


function getcss(cssfile){

    var loadcss = document.createElement('link')

    loadcss.rel = "stylesheet"

    loadcss.setAttribute("type", "text/css")

    loadcss.setAttribute("href", cssfile)

    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(loadcss)

}

if(isMobile.any() == true)
// Defines the resolution range you're targeting (less than 800 pixels wide in this case)

{

getcss('cssclass.css')
// Defines the .css file you want to load for this range (800x600.css)

}

else 

{

getcss('css2menuPage.css') 
//This else statement has "if" condition. If none of the following criteria are met, load 1280x1024.css

}
```

Comment: Consider using media queries instead.  They are a lot easier to deal with, and you won't have to use user-agent sniffing.

Comment: When you paste code, highlight it and click the code button (looks like some brackets).  You can also simply indent it and paste.  Finally, if you have a small bit you want to highlight, you can wrap it in back ticks.  Also, it looks like you are missing a line or two up top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@media screen size is like Brad mentioned above.  Otherwise you'll need to setup a database of user agents.

@media screen and (max-width:960px) { h1, h2 { color:#990000; font-size:1.4em; } }